# Advantages of SharePoint foundation 2010 over drupal

Tags: sharepoint, drupal

I am trying to build CMS using sharepoint foundation 2010 or drupal. We already have .net environment in place.

Could you please list what are advantages of sharepoint foundation 2010 over drupal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that with SharePoint you can build an "All Microsoft solution". You have easy integration with Active Directory, Office, BizTalk, plus Microsoft users get the look and feel that they're used to.

From the Drupal point of view, take a look at this article: [Drupal vs. SharePoint from a Developer's Viewpoint](http://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/drupal-vs-sharepoint). I can agree with all the SharePoint downsides mentioned there.

Comment: does share point foundation 2010 have any extra features that drupal doesnt have??

Comment: well, they are different systems with different tools, and I haven't worked with drupal enough to answer that. Maybe some drupal expert can shed some light on the topic?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do, and who the people are that work with the site.

If you're looking at building a highly customized, internet facing site that doesn't have a major data input pipeline from intranet sources, then SharePoint is not the right tool for the job, and if you have narrowed your choices down to Drupal or SharePoint, Drupal is likely the right answer.

If you're looking for something that can pull data from a number of sources, including a bunch of business folks that don't know much about how the web site really works (such as data from an Excel spreadsheet in your site), or you have a limited budget to write custom code, then you're likely better off with SharePoint. The drawbacks in the linked article apply, however, lists are a LOT friendlier and more powerful to non-developers than direct database access.